# Back button and forward button not working properly after query param set from a input field react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Any help is much appreciated. I have a application in which for searching I use an input field. What I type into input field should be set into url params with debounce. I am using history.push for that. After that when I hit back button or forward button the url params change which should be reflected in the input field. For that I am using setState of the input field. Because of this the back and forward button is not working properly.
Is there anyway I can update the field without using setState and make the field has the value from query param

Comment: Can anyone help? I need the query param and input field to be in sync

Comment: Please share the parts of your code which are relevant to your question.